# Ruby cucumber gems version

Tags: ruby, rspec

I started learn Ruby (for automation tests) in Rubymine but I have a problem with gems.
I downloaded some projects from github but I am not able to run projects Same with some tutorials.
Now as i understand:
EVERY project should have GEM FILE with gem versions.
It is possible to have projects with different version
bundles should take care of gems (but i have the problem with this)

My version ruby :2 .2.4
cucumber 2.2.4 gem 2.4.5.1

Do you recommend RVM? How can I correct install this(I downloaded something for key and sing up but no email with password) I could not use also curl command
I tried using : https://rvm.io/rvm/install

I am using RubyMine(for 30days so soon will finish:(() I used e.g https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap

and here I have:
alidate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.2.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of questions in this question. Please ask just one question and give enough detail about what you tried and what results you got.

Comment: Sorry. Ok, I am using different projects and tutorials from internet and still have a problem with gems. I am not sure how to use properly gems to work . I would like to understand the process of using them.Do you recommend RVM to use this? Do you recommend some tutorial? Should I have first git installed?

Comment: @pav: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I tried this on windows 10 I have also VM box with ubuntu but the same problems;(